# Types of scans performed by OWASPZAP

Tags: security, owasp, zap, penetration-testing, security-testing

I have started working with OWASPZAP (Manual Scans) and till now the learning and simultaneous execution had been exciting.

I did a Passive Scan on our Application and have found 3 Alerts and have interpreted the *Description* / *OtherInfo* / *Solution* / *Reference* which are as follows:

- `X-Frame-Options Header Not Set`: (Risk: Medium, Confidence: Medium, Parameter: X-Frame-Options)
- `Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled`: (Risk: Low, Confidence: Medium, Parameter: X-XSS-Protection)
- `X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing`: (Risk: Low, Confidence: Medium, Parameter: X-Content-Type-Options)

My questions are:

- Is there a way to know about the type of scans OWASPZAP would perform before the Scan starts?
- Are the Scans (Manual) configurable?
- Is there any documentation on the types of scans OWASPZAP (manual) performs?

**Note**: Of-coarse the question directly involve tools (e.g. OWASPZAP) used primarily for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wiki page that covers "[ZAPping the top 10](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/guides/zapping-the-top-10/)"

There are a number of help pages available with descriptions of the various scan rules or plugins:
Active Scan:

- Release -
  https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/active-scan-rules/
- Beta -
  https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/active-scan-rules-beta/
- Alpha -
  https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/active-scan-rules-alpha/

Passive Scan:

- Release -
  https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/passive-scan-rules/
- Beta -
  https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/passive-scan-rules-beta/
- Alpha - https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/passive-scan-rules-alpha/

You can create a Standalone script to run within ZAP to get the details of Active Scanners: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/master/standalone/Active%20scan%20rule%20list.js. Using a weekly release (newer than early March 2018) or the next stable release (2.8.0 or whatever) you'll be able to do something similar for passive scan rules leveraging `ExtensionPassiveScan.getPluginPassiveScanners()`

Creating Active Scan Policy(ies) can be done via the [Scan Policy Manager Dialog](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/scanpolicymgr/). Active Scan policies can be saved, exported, and imported. 
Enabled/disabling Passive Scan rules can be done via the [Options Passive Scan Rules screen](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/pscanrules/). (A Passive Scan "policy" can be established programmatically as discussed here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288461/7718222)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer along with the references.