# how to use ZAP to scan HTTP security header?

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy, zap

We want to integrate python/ZAPv2 into our SDLC, sometimes we only want to use ZAP to validate the security header, such as HttpOnly flag in Set-Cookie, CSP header, etc...

I google a lot, and find maybe ZAP policy could help us... but there is very limited document about how to self-define a zap policy, and how to call the API to call self-defined policy in ZAPv2 library

Is there any document/advices/ ideas could help me ...? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security header checks are generally implemented as passive scan rules (so if you spider or proxy traffic you can get results for them). Here's some info on setting a Passive Scan "policy" programmatically.

Re-using my answer from over here: [Export/Import OWASP ZAP Passive Scan Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266590/export-import-owasp-zap-passive-scan-rules)

---

There's an existing ticket open to unify Active/Passive Scan handling in a singular policy type interface: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/3870. 
If you're really interested in that you could support it on BountySource (https://www.bountysource.com/issues/49047644-improved-active-passive-rules-management) and see if that draws some attention/action.

Another option you could go with is to create a quick script that uses ZAP's web API to apply a Passive Scan rule "policy". Relevant endpoints include: pscan/view/scanners/, pscan/action/disableAllScanners/, pscan/action/enableScanners/. Here's a python example:

```
from zapv2 import ZAPv2 as zap
import time

apikey = "apikey12345" #Your apikey
z = zap(apikey=apikey, proxies={"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8080", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"})
time.sleep(2) #Might need to be longer depending on your machine and if ZAP is already running or not

print "Disabling all passive scan rules.."

z.pscan.disable_all_scanners()

scanners = z.pscan.scanners

for scanner in scanners:
    print scanner.get("id") + " : " + scanner.get("enabled") + " : " + scanner.get("name")

to_enable = "10020,10021,10062" #Customize as you see fit
print "\nEnabling specific passive scan rules..[" + to_enable +"]"

z.pscan.enable_scanners(to_enable)

print "\nListing enabled passive scan rules.."

scanners2 = z.pscan.scanners

for scanner in scanners2:
    if (scanner.get("enabled") == "true"):
        print scanner.get("id") + " : " + scanner.get("enabled") + " : " + scanner.get("name")
```

Finally you could configure ZAP on one system, then copy that `config.xml` to other systems as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but what is the meaning of "to_enable = "10020,10021,10062" " what does these code stand for....?

Comment: to_enable contains the list of plugin IDs you want to enable.